# constructor passing strings with specific format

Tags: java, constructor

For my project, I have to create a program that checks for valid dates. One of the constructors accepts a string as a parameter with the following format: “4/23/2012” where 21 indicates day, 9 indicates month,  and 2016 indicates year. You can assume the input has no errors  (i.e., a valid set of numbers) contained within and the year is a 4 digit number. I am not sure how to do this.

Background: There are three variables: int day, int month, int year.

Thanks

Comment: *" the following format: “4/23/2012” where 21 indicates day, 9 indicates month, and 2016 indicates year."* ... what? You may want to rethink your example.

Comment: You can use `String.split("/")` to divide the string into 3 components. Then `month=Integer.parseInt(string[0]`, `day=Integer.parseInt(string[1]`, `year=Integer.parseInt(string[2]`. Then you can use if statements to check the validity of each component.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what your goal is. Do you just want to validate the date-string and store it? If so you could do something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y");
dtf.parse(date); // Throws an exception when the date is the wrong format
```

Or do you want to split the date into its components and store them separately? In any case check out the Javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html